# QT QtableWidgetItem display formated data and sort by original data

Tags: qt, formatting, qtablewidgetitem

In a column in a `QTableWidget` I want to display some `double` values. By doing the following, I get my desired display:

```
double value = 1234.567;
QTableWidgetItem* qti = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(value , 'f', 4));
```

Now, if I enable sorting on the table and sort the values in this column, it will sort as strings. So `90.0000` will come be "larger" than `800.0000` for example (9 > 8).

If I do this instead:

```
QTableWidgetItem* qti = new QTableWidgetItem();
qti->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, value);
```

or

```
QTableWidgetItem* qti = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(value , 'f', 4));
qti->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, value);
```

I can sort my column correctly, but I "lose" the formmating (`12.0000` is displayed as `12`).

I've also tried like this:

```
QTableWidgetItem* qti = new QTableWidgetItem();
qti->setData(Qt::UserRole, value);
qti->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, QString::number(value, 'f', 4));
```

How can I format the display of the values, while still enabling sorting?

(In all code snippets above, the `QTableWidgetItems`' are added by:

```
table->setItem(rowNumber, colNumber, qti);
```

where table is a `QTableWidget`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it wrong. Let's do it right. The solution is to subclass QTableWidgetItem.

```
class CustomTableWidgetItem : public QTableWidgetItem
{

public:

    CustomTableWidgetItem(const QString txt = QString("0"))
        :QTableWidgetItem(txt)
    {
    }

    bool operator <(const QTableWidgetItem& other) const
    {
        qDebug() << "Sorting numbers";
        return text().toFloat() < other.text().toFloat();
       // text() is part of QTableWidgetItem, so you can write it as QTableWidgetItem::text().toFloat() as well
    }
};
```

Example insertions

```
    ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(false);
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(0);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, new CustomTableWidgetItem(QString::number(90.0005, 'f', 4)));
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(1);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(1, 0, new CustomTableWidgetItem(QString::number(800.0003, 'f', 4)));
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(2);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(2, 0, new CustomTableWidgetItem(QString::number(200.0010, 'f', 4)));
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(3);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(3, 0, new CustomTableWidgetItem(QString::number(200.0020, 'f', 4)));
    ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

Sorting behaviour is as expected

ascending

```
90.0005
200.0010
200.0020
800.0003
```

descending

```
800.0003
200.0020
200.0010
90.0005
```

**PS: Remember to turn off sorting before you insert bew items.**

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is by using `QStyledItemDelegate` attached to the double column(s). It need not do much except implement the `QStyledItemDelegate::displayText()` function.

For further details, see [QTableView and display of doubles](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45828) at Qt Centre.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with, based on Mangesh's answer, for a similar problem displaying a percentage:

```
class percentageItemC : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    QString displayText(const QVariant &value, const QLocale &locale) const
    {
        return QString::asprintf("%0.3lf%% ", value.toDouble());
    }
} percentageItem;
```

That's any number of digits to the left of the decimal, 3 to the right, and a long float with a percent sign.  Then, do a

```
ui->twMyTable->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, &percentageItem);
```

in yer form's class.  I can also re-use them for other columns, and presumably rows.

This method doesn't slow things down with extra text to float conversions.  You can also have nice extras, like commas, percent signs and currency signs in it.  I have this for currency:

```
class currencyItemC : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    QString displayText(const QVariant &value, const QLocale &locale) const
    {
        return locale.toCurrencyString(value.toDouble()) + " ";
    }
} currencyItem;
```

I use:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setData(Qt::EditRole, number);
```

to create the table items.  It is smart about these: it creates a QVariant, and then sorts based on the type.  This way, you don't have to set the underlying data to a string, but it can be any type it has a sort for.

The columns sort numerically like they're s'posed to, but they display in any format ya like. ;}

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the best option to solve this problem is to create new class with usage of  `setData()` with `Qt::UserRole` to store unformatted data. In this setup you can store real data and text together. This has more memory consumption but you doesn't need to convert from `string` to `int/float/etc`.

I've tested many other roles `Qt::EditRole, Qt::DisplayRole, etc` and they are overwriting stored data/text and you can't store both values.

Here is my final solution of class displaying `%` percent values (python code)

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class PercentTableWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem):
    # Float value
    value: float = 0

    def __init__(self,
                 value: float = 0
                 ):
        ''' Constructor.'''
        super().__init__()
        # Set variables
        self.value = value

        # Set item data
        self.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, value)
        self.setText(f'{self.value:.2f}%')

    def __lt__(self, other: QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem):
        ''' Operation < for sorting.'''
        value = other.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        return (value is not None) and (self.value < value)
```

Usage in code as simple as below

```py
table = QTableWidget()
table.setItem(0,0,PercentTableWidgetItem(35.67))
```